# Iphone square radio button issue

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have problem with radio button displaying on mobile version ( it looks square) but on desktop verion it looks fine.
[image: Image from my phone]

[image: This is image from my desktop - it must looks like here]

Comment: Whats the issue? How we can help? Do you have piece of code you think it relevant in fixing? The picture doesnt say anything I'm sorry. Please follow the guide set by Stackoverflow

Comment: I added one more image from desktop how it must look like on phone. I don't have code because I don't know what need to be fix

Comment: it just may be related to all those node errors piped into the html output

Comment: This radio UI may be native. Try giving border-radius:50% to the radio button

Comment: That is because the mobiles use different resources. You can try replacing the input with a stilized before applied to the label in CSS and hiding the default input radio.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have their default styling for various kind of elements. That's what you're seeing. You'll have to override the default styling to get the look you want.
(https://moderncss.dev/pure-css-custom-styled-radio-buttons/)